# Can't suddenly connect to my Firebase database

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

My issue is that all of a sudden I can't connect to my Firebase database, hence, in my case, users can't log in to my app. The issue came suddenly; my app passed Apple's review 2 days ago.

However, I only face this problem running the app on iPhone. I can still connect from Ipad!?

This OP recently had similar issue: [iphone/ipad suddenly stops responding to firebase queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752966/iphone-ipad-suddenly-stops-responding-to-firebase-queries). In my case however I can't read nor write from/to database. Tried "activating" the database like answer suggests but nothing happens. Haven't found anything helpful elsewhere.

As of May there's some new Firebase syntax which I updated my code with. I write to my database like this, which is correct according to the docs...

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child(someString).setValue(someValue)
```

...and query it like this...

```
databaseRef.child(someString).queryOrdered(byChild: someString).queryEqual(toValue: someValue).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in })
```

Nothing happens.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: For `.setValue(someValue)`, try `.setValue(someValue, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in  print(error) })` and see what is printed in Xcode output from iPhone

Comment: Thanks @EthanT, but nothing is printed. As I reckon the database isn't being called at all.

Comment: Are you seeing anything about App Transport Security in the output? I remember having a problem with an external API due to iOS protecting network requests, maybe this is something similar.

Comment: No. As I said, this issue arose just the other day. My app has been functioning with firebase for over a year

Comment: @EthanT, I appreciate your time and effort

Comment: That's odd :/ Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: @DanAbnormal If you didn't change anything, it is probably better to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. But I recommend trying to [reproduce the problem in a minimal new project](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will make it much easier to help (either here or in support).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks. I will try that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen. Quick question after comparing the logs of my dysfunctional iPhone and my functioning iPad: can "INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file..." be something worth looking further into? This appears only in my iPhone log and as far as I know hasn't shown before. Unfortunately I can't make anything of it...thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the file name from that error message?  Would help to know where it's coming from.

Comment: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D6A918FD-C7B9-4155-B723-E21B53A48ADB/Library/Caches/,,,Errno: 2

Comment: Thanks. The ",,," at the end of the filename looks suspicious, though I don't know what might be causing it. Anyway, hopefully support can help you out.  They should be able to help you enable logging which may yield some insights.

Comment: The ",,," is s typo. Sorry about that, didn't notice it before. I contacted support. We'll see what happens. Thanks for your time

Comment: Just an update. The issue seems to be device dependant; some users apparently don't experience any issues...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this answer [iphone/ipad suddenly stops responding to firebase queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752966/iphone-ipad-suddenly-stops-responding-to-firebase-queries) did work for me after all.

Right before the query I just call

```
databaseRef.setValue(someValue)
```

This  doesn't add anything to the database. However it seems to be what "wakes it up".

I'm afraid I can't tell you why or even if this is needed, but perhaps it's not a good idea to query the database first thing? Just a thought...

Thanks everyone who tried to help, and thank you @Carlos De la Mora for providing the answer to the question referred to above.

Comment: That sounds very weird. Did you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/), so that we can have a look at your log files and see if they give a hint at the cause of this?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. Glad it worked though. I have an ongoing contact with support. When we spoke on thursday and friday they could see nothing wrong, however now I see in my status dashboard that my database service was disrupted thursday morning. Haven't asked them about that yet so I don't know if it may have caused the problems I was facing.

Comment: We indeed had an outage late last week (I'm not completely sure of the timing, but the times in the dashboard should be correct). If the problem disappeared because of that, I'd rather close your question as "ephemeral/can't reproduce" since it won't be useful to others (and you've already been red heringed by Carlos' answer, which may have had a similar cause).

Comment: How do I close my question that way?

Comment: I don't think you have that option on your own question. But I have it as an option in the Close menu. Others do too. It'll happen... or not, in which case it's also not important enough to worry about. :-)

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. I'm not too used to SO. Sounds like an appropriate closure.